# Sorting with a function , no result

Tags: qt, sorting, c++11, path-finding

I want to sort a list based on the shortest path to a destination.

I use the sort function, so i go from begin to the end and calculate which is the best path to go to the next enemy.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Enemy>> ek = model->getAllEnemies();
std::sort( ek.begin(), ek.end(), customLess);
```

changed it to a struct:

```
struct {
        bool operator()(const std::shared_ptr<Enemy> &e, const std::shared_ptr<Enemy> &nexthp)
        {
            int pathcost = findPathfindingNodes(e->getXPos(), e->getYPos(),true);
            int pathcost2 = findPathfindingNodes(nexthp->getXPos(), nexthp->getYPos(),true);
            return pathcost < pathcost2;
        }
    } customLess;
```

But when i want to use the findpathfindingnodes function which is declared in the same .cpp file it gives an error :

```
/controller.cpp:235: error: 'findPathfindingNodes' was not declared in this scope
             int pathcost = findPathfindingNodes(e->getXPos(), e->getYPos(),true);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no result"? What exactly is going wrong? In which context do you call sort() and where is findPathfindingNodes() declared? Did you try with a lambda?

Comment: I updated my code, I now worked with the struct in the same .cpp file but still cannot find the findPathfindingNodes(). I haven't used lambda yet, how should I write it with lambda?

Comment: `findPathfindingNodes(..)` is not a method of `customLess`, that's why the compiler is complaining. Lambdas aren't going to help you if you don't understand basic scoping rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just include the class that has that function in it...

```
class SomeClass
{
    public:
        SomeClass();
        int findPathfindingNodes();
}
```

then wherever you want to use it make sure you have included the class
`#include "SomeClass"`

then just create an instance of it and call the function

```
SomeClass instance_of_some_class();
int result = instance_of_some_class.findPathfindingNodes();
```